# Is it possible for a double mouse middle click to activate the overview?

Tags: gnome, mouse, 17.04

When it comes to using my computer, I am a very modal person. When I am actively doing work, I have made it so that I can perform nearly all functionality with my keyboard (using a variety of shortcuts to launch applications, etc).

However, when I am passively browsing the web, I really prefer to just use my mouse. Now I am aware of the hot corner in Gnome and [other ways to edit the functionality](/q/653424), however, it would really help my work flow if there was a way to double middle and activate the overview. Even if it's a way to do it programmatically, it would be a worthwhile investment for me to undertake.

I have attached some information about my computer. I use Ubuntu version 17.04 and the gnome desktop environment (but I am considering a switch to budgie or xfce, so if either of those offer this functionality, I just might make the switch).

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty
```

Comment: A single middle click on the desktop would also work for me.